# Finding linear recurrence for a sequence which depend on another recurrence

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations

I stumbled upon a sequence of numbers $b_n$ such that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$,  $$b_n=\sum_{j=0}^M a_{n,j}$$
where $a_{n,j}$ are given by the recurrence,

$$a_{n,j}=\begin{cases}
1 & n=0 &\land &j=0\\
0 & n=0 &\oplus &j=0\\
\sum_{i=0}^M \lambda_{i,j}\cdot a_{n-1,i} & 0<n\in\mathbb{N} & \land & 0<j\leq M
\end{cases}$$

Is it possible to find a linear recurrence for $b_n$ based on that? Hopefully it can be done explicitly.

Comment: And what is $\,\lambda_{i,j}\,$?

Comment: They are rational numbers in my case. I thought their precise formula was abit complicated not relevant and hoped it could be done in general, as they are somewhat arbitrary

Comment: Not really clear what's going on with those conditions. Do you mean to have "and" or "or"s in there?

Comment: The first and third are 'and'. The second is precisely one of them is zero. I will try to edit it in tommorow, but I'm not sure how to write it better.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any immediate way for this to be rewritten into a linear recurrence. However, we can get a closed form. Let us rewrite

$$a_n=\begin{bmatrix}a_{n,0}\\a_{n,1}\\\vdots\\a_{n,M}\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\lambda=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_{0,0}&\lambda_{1,0}&\cdots&\lambda_{M,0}\\\lambda_{0,1}&\lambda_{1,1}&\cdots&\lambda_{M,1}\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\\lambda_{0,M}&\lambda_{1,M}&\cdots&\lambda_{M,M}\end{bmatrix}$$

with $\lambda_{i,0}=0$.

We then have

$$a_n=\lambda^n\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

and finally,

\begin{align}b_n&=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{bmatrix}^\intercal a_n\\&=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{bmatrix}^\intercal\lambda^n\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{bmatrix}\end{align}

which can be used to quickly compute $b_n$ for large $n$, among other things.